# In R confused about inferences I'm getting from logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic

Currently, I'm using Wisconsin Breast Cancer Dataset and running the logistic regression on the dataset. When I'm using the whole dataset for the logisitc regression I've almost 30 features which are significant (p-value less like between 0.1 & 0.001 ). But when I use a subsample say 80% of the data for fitting all my variables are not significant.

```
fit.glm<-glm(diagnosis~.,data = data1, family = binomial)
summary(fit.glm)
smp_size <- floor(0.8* nrow(data1))


set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(data1)), size = smp_size)

train <- data1[train_ind, ]
test <- data1[-train_ind, ]

fit.glm1<-glm(formula=diagnosis~.,binomial(link="logit"),data=train)
summary(fit.glm1)
```

This is the code I wrote for it.

**This is the result using all the data:**
[image: This is using all the data]

**This is the result using 80% of data:**
[image: This is using 80% of data]

You can see that all variables are becoming insignificant after using 80% of data and I also tried with 95% of the dataset and the same thing happened. I'm curious to understand why it' happening

Comment: How can you explain the huge coefficients in the first model?

Comment: How many cases are there in the smallest diagnosis class?

Comment: @EdM- The sample size is 569, so for training, I used 80% of 569  around 456 samples randomly picked.

Comment: @MichaelM- I didn't observe the coefficient values, all my focus was on  p-values I can't explain that one as well

Comment: Be careful not to add anything, even a "-", after a user name in a comment on this system, just leave a space. I just happened to find your reply on revisiting the page; it didn't show up in my queue of comments to review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably coming from perfect or near-perfect [separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separation?sort=votes) in your logistic regression analysis of the full data set.

With a large number of predictors it is common to find that some combination of them happens perfectly to distinguish the 2 classes *in your particular data set*. That can lead to difficulties in performing the analysis at all, very large apparent regression coefficients, or instability of results from subsample to subsample.

So in your example I would suspect separation in your full data set, leading to the extremely large coefficients. As MichaelM points out in a comment, you really do have to pay attention to the magnitudes of coefficients; do you really think that it's reasonable to expect a single predictor to have a million-fold influence on the log-odds of class membership? That's what a coefficient of `1e+06` means. It's not good practice just to focus on *p*-values.

Then when you look at a subset the (highly data-dependent) separation disappears, as might be expected.

Penalized regression approaches like ridge or LASSO can help work around this type of problem.

Comment: +1. One question: wouldn't perfect separation also occur on the subset?

Comment: @MichaelM it could be very dependent on the subset. Yes, if you re-applied the model from the entire dataset to the subset you would have perfect "prediction," but there's no assurance that a model _developed from a particular subset_ would show perfect separation. Might, might not. That said, the magnitudes of the coefficients still look really large in the subset analysis here. Hard to say too much about the coefficient magnitudes unless we know the units in which the predictors are expressed.